# how to add and remove a text file in a folder on a windows pc from an anddroid app

Tags: android, windows, networking, file-io

i have three folders on a windows 7 desktop PC, and each folder holds a file that corresponds to an an android tablet

```
 windows PC                android tablet

 folder one    <------->   android tablet one
 folder two    <------->   android tablet two
 folder three  <------->   android tablet three
```

i want to at the touch of a button on the android tablet app copy a simple text file from the folder on the windows computer to the tablet, and when i touch another button on the android tablet copy the same file in the other direction, from the tablet to the folder on the windows pc.

i want to avoid writing any software for the windows PC and do it all from the tablet.

how can this be done?  what is the best way?

i was considering dropbox API but i don't think it is possible as there are 3 different files and there are 3 separate tablets.  so it is not possible to run 3 different dropboxes on the same computer.

Comment: Did you try `adb pull` and/or `adb push`?

Comment: does the tablet need to be rooted to do this?

Comment: No, if you are pushing/pulling files to/from SD card.

Comment: You can use airdroid app. http://www.airdroid.com/